# What does "drink the pain away" mean?

Tags: idioms, lyrics

What does "drink the pain away" or "drinking my pain away" mean?

I've heard it in a song by Nicky Jam & Enrique Iglesias named Forgiveness.
Here is the related part of the original lyrics:

> I'm missing you baby
>      Up all night goin' crazy
>      Now my angel can't save me
>      Oh no!!!
>      I'm missing you baby
>      Up all night goin' crazy
>      Drinking my pain away-ehh-hey

Comment: If you could include a source of where you saw this phrase or the sentences before and after it, it might help us explain it more precisely in context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Drinking", without an object, is usually taken as referring to alcohol. So "drinking the pain away" means drinking so much alcohol that the pain goes away somehow - by being forgotten, being surpassed by some other drunken activity, or some other method of numbing the pain.